# What is the role of this telescopic pole-looking item in the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, joists, stairs

I've recently viewed a property and done a first pass at the work that will need doing. But, I noticed this in the ceiling of the stairwell and I'm not entirely sure of a few things:

- What exactly is it? (seems like telescopic pole or jack of some sort?)
- What purpose is it?
- What further inspections or work items should I make off the back of this?

I've noted that the paint marks are misaligned, indicating this has been altered since installation and likely has been installed for some time.

[image: Stairwell shot]

[image: Close up shot]

Comment: the pictures do not show enough detail .... it looks like a hot water pipe covered with insulation ... you are the only one that can actually touch the thing, so do some investigating .... don't just take a picture ... downvote for not showing any effort to answer your own question

Comment: My guess was radiator pipe, what type of heat does this building have?

Comment: It looks like some sort of pipe. Beyond that, I have no clue what it's carrying or why it's been exposed.

Comment: Looks like a light fitting - two tubular filament bulbs, the type often used in kitchens for undershelf lighting perhaps. [These](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Main_Index/Lighting_Menu_Index/Lamps_and_Tubes_Index/Tubular_Strip_Lamps/index.html) are LED replacements in the same form factor. I can't find a picture of the filament version.